# Is there a way to get the size of a three-dimensional vector using pointer notation?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, array-pointer

I need to do something like this:

```
sizeof(int[width][height][8])
```

but unfortunately in c89 (the standard i have to use) this notation is forbidden, is there any way to do the same thing but using pointer notation?

[Here's the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYXL9.png)

It works fine in c99 but not in c89

Comment: *c89 (the standard i have to use)*  Hopefully that's a hardware restriction and not some brain-damaged artificial limitation.  Otherwise why not restrict you to stone tablets and an abacus?

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of text but post text as text directly in the question.

Comment: Even if you figure out the `sizeof` (which is a simple matter of multiplication), you won't be able to declare a variable of that type anyway.

Comment: Your error is clearly stated by the compiler: this is forbidden. Understand it as impossible to achieve. If compilation passes, I am quite sure this will still lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this instead:

```
(sizeof(int) * (width) * (height) * 8)
```

Make sure you put the `sizeof(int)` first to force `width` and `height` to be converted to `size_t` and avoid a potential integer overflow on `width * height * 8` if `width` and `height` have `int` type.